# Give permission to an account to create subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a new user under Azure Active Directory by using the invite option. Then I assigned every single administrative role to that account but it still doesn't have access to create a new subscription. When you try to create a subscription with that account it give the following message

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to create a subscription? Can you share related document or steps?

Comment: I logged in to portal.azure.com -> Subscriptions -> Add -> It takes me to my other directory -> I switch back to the directory that I want -> And then I get the above message

Comment: Hi, @Almis. Have you added the `Billing Administrator` role to make it work?  If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a `Billing Administrator` role to the new guest user.

You could refer to the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal) to assign role.